Interpreting interaction term
Suppose I am interested in estimating the effect of a treatment (vs a control), fully and conditional on different levels (say, 3) of a baseline caracteristic (say, income level). I would have a regression (T is treatment, I is income levels 1-3) as follows :
$Y = a + b_1T + b_2T(x=1) + b_3T(x=2) + b_4T(x=3) + e$
I am not sure I understand what the three interaction terms are being compared against : is it the "pure control" or b1 ? In other words, are we using data from income levels from the control group to run this regression ? Or are we just comparing outcomes for b2, b3 and b4 to outcomes from b1 ?
Thanks !

Should it not be "b4TxI" rather than "b4xI" ?

I tried to edit your formula for clarity. Let me know if I failed (or just make further corrections).

There is no "comparison" in this formula, so please tell us what you mean by "being compared against."  It sounds like you might have in mind some kind of default test of parameters, but it would be better for you to tell us rather than have us guess.

@PeterFlom Shouldn't $b+3T(x=2)$ be $b_3T(x=2)$?

Setup

Treatment: 2 levels (treated, control)
Income: 3 levels (Low, Medium, High)

Treatment Contrasts
Treatment contrasts create binary (0/1) variables to compare each level of a categorical variable to a reference level. Suppose we choose:

For treatment: Control  as the reference level.
For income: Low as the reference level.

Model Specification
The regression model can be written as:
$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \text{Treatment}_\text{Treated} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{Income}_\text{Medium} + \beta_3 \cdot \text{Income}_\text{High} + \beta_4 \cdot (\text{Treatment}_\text{Treated} \times \text{Income}_\text{Medium}) + \beta_5 \cdot (\text{Treatment}_\text{Treated} \times \text{Income}_\text{High}) + \epsilon
$$
Interpretation of Estimates:

Intercept ($\beta_0$): The expected value of $y$ when both treatment and income are at their reference levels (Control and Low income, respectively).

$\beta_1$: The difference in the expected value of $y$ between the Treated group and the Control group when income is at the Low level.

$\beta_2$: The difference in the expected value of $y$ between the Medium income group and the Low income group when treatment is Control.

$\beta_3$: The difference in the expected value of $y$ between the High income group and the Low income group when treatment is Control.

$\beta_4$: The additional difference in the effect of treatment on $y$ for the ``Medium'' income group compared to the Low income group. This is the interaction effect between treatment and Medium income.

$\beta_5$: The additional difference in the effect of treatment on $y$ for the High income group compared to the Low income group. This is the interaction effect between treatment and High income.


Example Interpretation
Suppose we have the following estimates:

$\beta_0 = 10$
$\beta_1 = 2$
$\beta_2 = 3$
$\beta_3 = 5$
$\beta_4 = 1$
$\beta_5 = -2$

Scenarios

Control group with Low income`:
$$
\hat{y} = 10
$$

Treated group with Low income`:
$$
\hat{y} = 10 + 2 = 12
$$

Control group with Medium income:
$$
\hat{y} = 10 + 3 = 13
$$

Control group with High income:
$$
\hat{y} = 10 + 5 = 15
$$

Treated group with Medium income:
$$
\hat{y} = 10 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 16
$$
Here, $2$ is the effect of being treated, $3$ is the effect of having medium income, and $1$ is the additional interaction effect.

Treated group with High income:
$$
\hat{y} = 10 + 2 + 5 - 2 = 15
$$
Here, $2$ is the effect of being treated, $5$ is the effect of having high income, and $-2$ is the interaction effect.


